# Batch Script Find String in String with a twist

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to do this in a batch script, which should be simple, but after spending a couple of hours on it I am no closer to a solution.

If the CMD parameter contains a series of letters, I want to surround each letter with single quotes and separate by commas. For example, if the user enter this:

```
MYTEST.CMD ABCDEF
```

I want to create a string that looks like this:

```
'A','B','C','D','E','F'
```

The same as if they had entered this in the CMD line:

```
MYTEST.CMD "'A','B','C','D','E','F'"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly easy, actually:

```
@echo off
set "LETTERS=%~1"
set OUTPUT=

if not defined LETTERS goto usage

:loop
  if defined OUTPUT set "OUTPUT=%OUTPUT%,"
  set "OUTPUT=%OUTPUT%'%LETTERS:~0,1%'"
  set "LETTERS=%LETTERS:~1%"
  if defined LETTERS goto loop

echo.%OUTPUT%
goto :eof

:usage
echo Please pass a few letters as argument, e.g.
echo.  %~0 ABC
goto :eof
```

Let's dissect it a little:

1. We first store the argument in the variable `LETTERS`.
2. Then we initialise our output string to an empty string.
3. Then follows a loop that appends the first letter from `LETTERS` to `OUTPUT` in the proper format (with a comma before if `OUTPUT` is not empty) and removes that letter from `LETTERS`.
4. When `LETTERS` is empty, we exit the loop and print the result.

And just for the fun of it, the same as a PowerShell function:

```
function Get-LetterList([string]$Letters) {
  ([char[]]$Letters | ForEach-Object { "'$_'" }) -join ','
}
```

Comment: Should use `set "letter=%~1"` in case argument is already quoted.

Comment: Good point, indeed. And if that is your only complaint then I did at least some things right ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below use an interesting trick I borrowed from [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5050) that convert the Ascii (1-byte) characters into Unicode 2-bytes characters via `cmd /U` (inserting a zero-byte between characters), and then split the zero-bytes in individual lines via `find` command:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "output="
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('cmd /D /U /C echo %~1^| find /V ""') do (
   set "output=!output!,'%%a'"
)
set output="%output:~1%"
echo %output%
```